# Meteor never see's me as looged in

Tags: meteor

I want to detect if a logged in user has no records in the collection and then start them with some default values. So I use this at the beginning of my isClient part;

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  if(Meteor.user()){
    Meteor.subscribe('collection');
    var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
    if (collection.find({"userID": currentUserId}).count() == 0)
    {       
      Meteor.call('initUser', currentUserId);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("You are not logged in");
  }
}
```

Problem is that it never see's me as logged in. Do I need to be calling this from a template or something? In the tutorial that I did they just had it all by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good to me but it does not live in a reactive computation, meaning that it's going to run only once at the beginning of your code and never again, just like regular sequential programming.

You need to surround your code with a `Tracker.autorun` like this :

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Tracker.autorun(function(){
    // Meteor.userId() is a reactive data source that will trigger invalidation
    // of the reactive computation whenever it is modified (on login/logout)
    var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
    if(currentUserId){
      Meteor.subscribe('collection',function(){
        if (collection.find({
          userID: currentUserId
        }).count() === 0){       
          Meteor.call('initUser', currentUserId);
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log("You are not logged in");
    }
  }
}
```

I've refactored it to only use `Meteor.userId()` because you don't use the `currentUser` properties in this piece of code.

Comment: Thanks! First I've heard of the Tracker.

Comment: One problem, every time that I log in it creates an additional copy of the collection for me, even though it's not doing `Meteor.call('initUser', currentUserId);` ? At first I had 10 items and now I am up to 140.

Comment: I refactored the code to put the `collection.find` test in the ready callback of the subscription http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe